# How to add DRM to EPUB?

Tags: drm, epub

I would like to add (not remove) DRM to an EPUB file? How would I do it? Preferably on OS X.

I tried Gooogling but (all) of them are about removing DRM from EPUB.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this DRM? Is this to secure a document for internal use, for paid distribution, or for some other purpose? See ["What is the XY problem?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need proprietary software made for adding DRM to ePUB's.

Check out Adobe's [Content Server](http://www.adobe.com/products/content-server.html) product line, as it implements a version of Adobe's DRM "ADEPT" (Adobe Digital Experience Protection Technology).

> Adobe® Content Server 4 software is a robust server solution that digitally protects PDF and reflowable EPUB eBooks for Adobe Digital Editions software and supported mobile devices, including the E Ink, smartphones, and tablet devices.

[More info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Digital_Editions) from Wikipedia.